# Is it possible to set a background png on a view and anchor it to the top and not scale in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have an image, say **16px** from our designer. I want to set it as the **background image on a view**, but the view is larger than the image. So, I want to **anchor the image at the top of the view**, and then have the view fill in the bottom with a **solid color**.

Is this possible in the current version of Android, 1.5_r3?

Here is what I have so far:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="3dip"
style="@style/listItemStyle">...
```

Where listItemStyle is defined as:

```
 <style
  name="listItemStyle"
  parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
   <item name="android:background">@drawable/list_background</item>
 </style>
```

But the image is scaling to take up the entire view, and I am not sure how to set the image as the background and specify a solid color at the same time.  I suspect I need to wrap the view in a containing view which has the color specified, is that the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your image in a **ImageView**, and then use the solid color as a background of the item view. This is one alternative.

Cheers